# PGFPfots: Filled marker does not correspond with legend

Tags: pgfplots, color, legend

I have two files from which I want to create a single scatter plot. For the marker, I use the meta option to give them a specific style based on a string value. However, the legend and the markers don't correspond. The filling of the green markers is blue, while the solid black markers are somehow also filled blue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
    Peak_m;f_d_m;Gitterart
    4.35E-01;898.0604651;D1
    1.85E-01;1029.977778;D1
    1.85E-01;1208.159091;D1
    2.975832444;734.6622222;D1
    0.796230549;921.1511111;D1
    3.34E-01;1107.706667;D1
    1.112616973;675.9333333;D1
    5.15E-01;883.7727273;D1
    5.61E-01;1070.271111;D1 
  }\dleer

  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{ 
    Gitterart;f_d_m;Peak_m
    m;1963.26;0.035093333   
  }\massiv

\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    scatterplot/.style={
      scatter,
      only marks,
      mark options={line width=1.3pt},
      scatter src=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        D1={green, mark=square*, fill=white},
        m={black, mark=*}
      }
    }
  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[every axis plot/.append style={scatterplot}]
            \addplot table[x=Peak_m, y=f_d_m, meta=Gitterart] {\dleer};
            \addplot table[x=Peak_m, y=f_d_m, meta=Gitterart] {\massiv};
            \legend{FCC, m}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]